# how to increase jdeveloper database connection timeout

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, jdeveloper

i am using SQL-Developer /J-Developer when I leave it for long time I got "connection time out " message 
how i can increase the Time out time ?

Comment: This may help you to keep connection alive in SQL/Developer: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2314890